# $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}$

Can we say answer is $0$ as $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x}=0$ or undefined because of $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1x $ is undefined

Answer (score 4):

First of all $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x}$ is NOT $\infty$. The limit from the right and left are $\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively, and hence not equal.

---

Next, the expression $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{x} - \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{x}$ is undefined, but not because it is "$\infty - \infty$". The symbol $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{x}$ itself has no meaning, because this limit doesn't exist. SO, logically it doesn't even make sense to write things like the difference of undefined things.

I'd say  the expression $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{x} - \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{x}$ has as much meaning as $\ddot{\smile} * \text{apple}$ (which in a math context, is no meaning whatsoever). As another illustration: what is spongebob times jupiter? You'll think I'm crazy for asking this question... like what is that even supposed to mean? That's the point I'm trying to illustrate here (although in your case it is much worse, because jupiter actually exists, whereas $\lim_{x\to 0}1/x$ doesn't)

Now, $\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x} \right)$ on the hand does make sense, and this limit exists and is equal to zero.

Now, when applying calculational rules, you need to know when exactly they are valid. Knowing the hypotheses of theorems is very important. Writing

> $\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

alone is meaningless. This is the analogue of writing an incomplete sentence in English (they are formally incorrect, and they make no sense strictly speaking).

A more complete statement is that

> If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exist (and note that "exist" means they have to be real numbers, which by definition are all finite), then $\lim_{x \to a}( f(x)+ g(x))$ also exists (i.e is a finite real number), and
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a}g(x)
> \end{align}

You see, theorems are supposed to be full English sentences. I could rewrite the entire theorem above using only words and no mathematical symbols (it would be very cumbersome to read and write math this way... but it is possible).

So, before you apply the "sum rule of limits", ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS check that the limits exist first. Only after that apply the rule. In your case $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x}$ doesn't even exist, so the sum/difference rule cannot be applied to it.

Comment: spongebob times jupiter LOL +1

Answer (score 3):

The limit of a difference is the difference of the limits and conversely *provided these limits exist*.

Comment: why we can't merge these limits. what we are violating here?

Comment: @prat: is my sentence unclear ?

Comment: actually I wanted to know the reason?

Comment: @prat: the reason of what ?

Comment: like why we can't merge the limits in this case. I know the rules, but what is the logic behind them.

Comment: @prat: because a theorem where some items are undefined (as stated explicitly) cannot be applied.